# Unable to set correct href link in IE with jquery address

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-address

Using jquery address I'm setting my href links like so:

```
<a href="#view_profile=123">view 123</a>
```

When calling my address change event:

```
$.address.change(function(e) {
   alert(e.value);
});
```

I see values from FF and Chrome as I would expect:

```
/view_profile=123
```

IE however returns the full URL path with a preceding "/" like so:

```
/http://localhost/#view_profile=123
```

Any idea why IE does this and what's the best way to fix it?  I've tried several things but it's the same every time.

Here is the code that I use to get the link path:

```
// Setup jQuery address on some elements
$('a').address();

// Run some code on initial load
$.address.init(function(e) {
  // Address details can be found in the event object
});

// Handle any URL change events
$.address.change(function(e) {
    alert(e.value);

    var urlAux = e.value.split('=');
    var page   = urlAux[0];
    var arg  = urlAux[1];

    alert("page: " + page);
    alert("arg: " + arg);

    if (page == "/view_profile") {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `e` and how does it relate to your anchor?

Comment: e is my event object and holds the value of the link in this case

Comment: the solution to this is going to be based on how you get the link value. can you post that code? The reason this happens is when you create an anchor tag dynamically in IE, the href property will always contain the absolute path regardless if you only supplied it a relative path. For an example, see this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/xKLKZ/

Comment: please see my code edits above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around. If I add a class tag to the link and look for a click event on the class I can set the URL and it triggers the jquery address change event correctly.

```
$(".testclass").click(function() {

    var id = null;
    if ($.browser.msie) {    
        id = $(this).attr('href').slice($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#')+1);
    } 
    else {    
        id = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
    }

    alert("ID: " + id );

    location.href = "#view_profile=" + id; 
    return false;
});
```

I also had to set the href value to the ID like so:

```
<a href="#123" class="testclass">123</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using $(this).prop("href") to get the url. it should get you the same value in all browsers.

Edit: pathname doesn't work in IE.

.. guess i should have done more testing. pathname doesn't work in IE. just use "href"